# How to copy compiled jade files to a destination folder using grunt

Tags: node.js, build-automation, pug, npm, gruntjs

For a single page app that I'm working on, I have the following structure:

- dist

  - css
  - js
  - lib
  - partials
  - index.html
- src

  - css
  - js
  - lib
  - views

    - partials
    - index.jade

Directory **dist** will be used by the express server to serve the project. I have trivial grunt tasks (using *grunt-contrib-clean*, *grunt-contrib-copy*) for cleaning **dist** and copying **src/css**, **src/js**, **src/lib** to **dist**.

The problem lies with **src/views**. This directory contains jade files which need to be compiled to html files. After compilation I want them in **dist** (index.html in the dist root, partials as subdir).

At the moment I am using the **grunt-contrib-jade** task to compile and copy the jade files. I want to copy them to dist, since I don't want to add the compiled html files to source control. But now this is not really workable, since you have to specify every jade file (now there are only a few, but that will grow):

```
   jade: {
        compile: {
            options: {
                pretty: true
            },
            files: {
                // TODO make one line
                'dist/index.html': ['src/views/index.jade'],
                'dist/partials/banner.html': ['src/views/partials/banner.jade'],
                'dist/partials/dashboard.html': ['src/views/partials/dashboard.jade'],
                'dist/partials/navbar.html': ['src/views/partials/navbar.jade'],
                'dist/partials/transfer.html': ['src/views/partials/transfer.jade']
            }
        }
    },
```

**Is there any way to use the grunt-contrib-jade task (or another one) with a directory filter?** Like this:

```
   jade: {
        compile: {
            options: {
                pretty: true
            },
            dir: {
                'dist': ['src/views']
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried the "Files Array Format" [described here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Configuring-tasks)? The example (using the concat task) sets the `dest` property to a directory: `files: [{src: ['src/bb.js', 'src/bbb.js'], dest: 'dest/b/'}]`. It's likely that the `jade-contrib` task also supports this format.

Comment: Didnt work. It copied all files into one file named '*.html' :) Tried 'files: grunt.file.expandMapping(['**/*.jade'], 'dist', {cwd: 'src/views'})' described on the same page, but i'm getting expandMapping is not defined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up upgrading to grunt 0.4 (which causes some other problems, but that I'll be able to handle).

With grunt version 0.4 it is possible to use [grunt.file.expandMapping](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.expandmapping):

```
    jade: {
        compile: {
            options: {
                pretty: true
            },
            files: grunt.file.expandMapping(['**/*.jade'], 'dist/', {
                cwd: 'src/views',
                rename: function(destBase, destPath) {
                    return destBase + destPath.replace(/\.jade$/, '.html');
                }
            })

        }
    },
```

Comment: ended up using something similar to this, and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Little clarification from [Grunt wiki - expand mapping](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.expandmapping):

```
grunt.file.expandMapping(patterns, dest [, options])
```

> Note that while this method may be used to programmatically generate a files array for a multi task, the declarative syntax for doing this described in the "Building the files object dynamically" section of the [Configuring tasks guide](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks) is preferred.

Assuming the above, configuration will look like this:

```
files: [ { 
  expand: true, 
  src: "**/*.jade", 
  dest: "dist/", 
  cwd: "src/views", 
  ext: '.html'
} ];
```

Same result with declarative configuration.

Comment: +1: This is indeed an option. rename function is not needed even, since the ext attribute does the job. Still, version 0.4 of grunt is needed, what was not clear at the beginning.

Comment: I don't know why but I have to remove [ ] form files: so `files: { ... }` works for me and `files: [{ ... }]` throw error ` Object #<Object> has no method 'indexOf'`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change only the extension of the files from .jade to .html, another option would be using the `flatten` and `ext` parameters like so:

```
jade: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            data: { debug: false, title: 'My awesome application' }
        },
        files: grunt.file.expandMapping(['**/*.jade'], '<%= yeoman.dist %>/views', {
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/views',
            flatten: true,
            ext: '.html'
       })
    }
}
```

Or even better (as explained [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Configuring-tasks)):

```
jade: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            data: { debug: false, title: 'My awesome application' },
            pretty: true
        },
        files: [
            {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/views',
                src: ['**/*.jade'],
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/views',
                ext: '.html'
            }
        ]}
}
```

Thanks.