# How can I rename files with Grunt, based on the respective file's parent folder name?

Tags: gruntjs, parent-child, rename, build-automation

I have a the following structure:

```
src/
    modules/
        module1/
            js/
                main.js
            scss/
                main.scss
            index.html
        module2/
            js/
                main.js
            scss/
                main.scss
            index.html
```

I'd like to run a grunt task to copy these out to the following structure:

```
dev/
    js/
        module1.js
        module2.js
    css/
        module1.css
        module2.css
    module1.html
    module2.html
```

Is there a way to do this with an existing grunt plugin? If not, how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

This can be done using the [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) plugin.

The main thing to note is that you can change the destination programmatically by using a rename function (which takes in the destination and source of each file).

Here is a (somewhat brittle) sample `Gruntfile.js` that should copy to your desired structure:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    copy: {
      main: {
        files: [
          {
            expand: true, 
            cwd: 'src/modules/', 
            src: ['**/*.js'], 
            dest: 'dev/js/', 
            rename: function(dest, src) {
              // use the source directory to create the file
              // example with your directory structure
              //   dest = 'dev/js/'
              //   src = 'module1/js/main.js'
              return dest + src.substring(0, src.indexOf('/')) + '.js';
            }
          },
          {
            expand: true, 
            cwd: 'src/modules/', 
            src: ['**/*.scss'], 
            dest: 'dev/css/', 
            rename: function(dest, src) {
              return dest + src.substring(0, src.indexOf('/')) + '.css';
            }
          },
          {
            expand: true, 
            cwd: 'src/modules/', 
            src: ['**/*.html'], 
            dest: 'dev/', 
            rename: function(dest, src) {
              return dest + src.substring(0, src.indexOf('/')) + '.html';
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['copy']);
};
```

Comment: Got reverse situation: needed to move files to different folders from one source. Your answer solved my problem, thanks!

Comment: also very important to note here is that if you want to skip certain files while renaming, the correct return value (the default) is `return dest+'/'+src` - which will cause the file to be copied to the default location.

Comment: So, just to do a simple command line operation like copying files, you have to install a plugin? Do you have to install a plugin for basically every operation?

Comment: @Jakobud no you can use built-in Node.js methods for filehandling, see http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html although they are just low level

Comment: In my case, I also use the rename as a filter function, and when encountering files I do not want to copy, I send them to `'/tmp/'+dest+'/'+src`. Neglecting to return a value from the `rename` function causes an error.

Comment: It seems this doesn't work anymore. There is no "rename" option in the current version (0.7.0) of grunt-conrib-copy

Comment: @Malki I believe the rename functionality is actually a feature of grunt itself (and not specific to grunt-contrib-copy). I tested with grunt@0.4.5 and grunt-contrib-copy@0.7.0 and the rename function still gets called for me. [Here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/0996ff7b2a333af07cf654c543bfff485888c405/lib/grunt/file.js#L165) is the code in grunt that runs the rename function. Let me know if there is an easy way to reproduce the issue you're having!

Comment: @Gloopy Thanks for the clarification! I tried it again and it works... I don't know what I did wrong the first time... probably some config mistake

Comment: My mistake was that I put "rename" under the "options" object for "copy", when it belonged in the top level object. Maybe that will help somebody :-).

Answer (score 6):

There's no need to use `grunt-contrib-copy` just for this any more, you can now take advantage of `grunt.file.expandMapping` which has options to just change the file extension, or to define a function that returns the output filename.

Here's an example of a `files` object in a `jade` task for compiling .jade templates into .html files:

```
files: [{
    expand: true, 
    src: "**/*.jade", 
    dest: "<%= distDir %>", 
    cwd: "<%= assetsDir %>/jade", 
    rename: function(dest, matchedSrcPath, options) {
        // return the destination path and filename:
        return (dest + matchedSrcPath).replace('.jade', '.html');
    }
}]
```

It would have been easier to use the `ext: '.html'` option instead of the `rename` option in this case, but I'm using `rename` here so you can see how it works.

More info about the `ext` and `rename` (and other) options in the [grunt.file docs](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.expandmapping). Some more examples [here](http://blog.frankmtaylor.com/2014/09/05/grunt-js-minify-rename-and-put-it-in-another-folder/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089921/how-to-copy-compiled-jade-files-to-a-destination-folder-using-grunt).

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use the options:
expand : true,
flatten: true

No need for custom rename callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

if u want to rename .coffee files to .js or similar then just adapt it ;)

sudo npm install grunt-contrib-copy

```
copy: {
  rename: {
    files: [{
     expand: true,
     dot: true,
     cwd: './app/scripts',
     dest: './app/scripts/',
     src: [
       '**/*.coffee'
     ],
     rename: function(dest, src) {
       console.log(dest + src);
       return dest + src.replace('.coffee','.js');
     }
   }]
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

**Not exactly an answer to your question** but i made it here looking for **relative dest folders with grunt** so... Here is how i solved it

```js
...
base: {
  files:
  [
    {
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'app/design/frontend/',
      src: ['**/Magento_Sales/email-src/*.html'],
      dest: '../../Magento_Sales/email/',
      rename: function(dest, src, expand) {
        src = path.parse(src)
        return path.join(expand.cwd, src.dir, dest, src.base);
      }
    },
  ],
}
...
```

This little bit `path.join(expand.cwd, src.dir, dest, src.base);` just creating the path i need.

`expand.cwd = app/design/frontend/`

`src.dir    = <DYNAMIC_FOLDERS>/Magento_Sales/email-src/`

`dest       = ../../Magento_Sales/email/`

`src.base   = <FILE>.html`

and all together it = `app/design/frontend/<COMPANY>/<MAIN-THEME>/Magento_Sales/email/<FILE>.html`

and in my situation it will now compile my html emails in relative destination folders

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to save the file in a min folder created at the root where we found the file so it's more easy to moove the plugin folder into another project :

```
-- Plugins/    
     -- bootstrap/                
            -- bootstrap.js
            -- bootstrap.css
            -- min/
                 -- bootstrap.min.js
                 -- bootstrap.min.css
```

I post the solution I found thanks to this page maybe it can help others :

```
uglify: {
    options: {
        mangle: true
    },
    dynamic_mappings: {
        // Grunt will search for "**/*.js" under "Plugins/" when the "uglify" task
        // runs and build the appropriate src-dest file mappings then, so you
        // don't need to update the Gruntfile when files are added or removed.
        files: [
            {
                expand: true,     // Enable dynamic expansion.
                cwd: 'Plugins/',  // Src matches are relative to this path.
                src: ['**/*.js', '!**/*.min.js'], // Pattern to match (ignore .min files)
                dest: '/min/',     // Destination path prefix.
                ext: '.min.js',   // Dest filepaths will have this extension.
                extDot: 'last',   // Extensions in filenames begin after the first dot
                rename: function( dest, matchedPath, options ) {

                    Pathname = matchedPath.substring( 0, matchedPath.indexOf('/') );
                    Filename = matchedPath.replace( Pathname, '' );

                    //Return "Plugins / plugin_folder / min / file_name.min.js"
                    return options.cwd + Pathname + dest + Filename;
                }
            },
        ],
    },
}
```