# is it possible to extract file name in a Grunt task (with the grunt-cmd-transport plugin)

Tags: gruntjs

i read the Grunt official documents and this post [respective file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271121/how-can-i-rename-files-with-grunt-based-on-the-respective-files-parent-folder/15516687#15516687)

unfortunately, i don't get a answer

I have the following file structure:

```
src/
    modules/
        module1/
            static/
                abc.js
                def.js
                ......
        module2/
            static/
                123.js
                456.js
                ......
```

and this is my Gruntfile fragment:

```
        module1: {
            options: {
                idleading: 'module1/static/'
            },
            files: [
                {
                    cwd: 'modules/module1/static',
                    src: '**/*.js',
                    dest: '.build/module1/static'
                }
            ]
        },
        module2: {
            options: {
                idleading: 'module2/static/'
            },
            files: [
                {
                    cwd: 'modules/module2/static',
                    src: '**/*.js',
                    dest: '.build/module2/static'
                }
            ]
        },
```

as you see, the two target is quite similar, the only difference is the "module" name, and we got about 20+ module...so it seems too stupid to copy the above configuration for 20+ times...

so my question is: can i find a way to write a function, to go through all directory, and extract the module name, then pass to the configuration like "cwd", "dest", "idleading"?

please show me solution directory, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

sorry to answer my own question. but i write a Gruntfile to solve this problem. i can't post it in a comment...

```
grunt.registerTask('recursive_transport', 'recursive every directory, and perform transport task', function () {

    var dirList = [];
    var root = "applications";

    (function walk(path) {
        var items = fs.readdirSync(path);
        items.forEach(function (item) {
            if (fs.statSync(path + '/' + item).isDirectory()) {
                dirList.push(path + '/' + item);
                walk(path + '/' + item);
            }
        });
    })(root);// search all directories

    // exclude special directory
    function isExcludeDir(dirName) {
        if (dirName.indexOf('test') > -1) {
            return true;
        }
        if (dirName.indexOf('service') > -1) {
            return true;
        }
        if (dirName.indexOf('css') > -1) {
            return true;
        }
        if (dirName.indexOf('html') > -1) {
            return true;
        }
        if (dirName.indexOf('3rd-lib') > -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    dirList.forEach(function (item, index) {

        item = item.substr((root + '/').length);// cut the leading path "applications/", then leaving "employee/static"

        if (!isExcludeDir(item)) {

            var targetName = "transport.build" + index;// such as 'transport.build0'

            grunt.config.set(targetName + '.options.idleading', item + '/');
            grunt.config.set(targetName + '.files', [
                {
                    cwd: root + '/' + item,
                    src: '*.js',
                    dest: '.build/' + item
                }
            ]);

            grunt.task.run(targetName.replace('.', ':'));
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah there is; what you're looking for is grunt-multi. I've played around with this a little bit and got a similar configuration working for a copy task, so hopefully this is of some use to you:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    transport: {
        modules: {
            options: {
                idleading: '<%= module %>/static/'
            },
            files: [
                {
                    cwd: 'modules/<%= module %>/static',
                    src: '**/*.js',
                    dest: '.build/<%= module %>/static'
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    multi: {
        modules: {
            options: {
                vars: {
                    modules: {
                        patterns: '*',
                        options: {
                            cwd: 'modules',
                            filter: 'isDirectory'
                        } 
                    }
                },
                config: {
                    module: '<%= modules %>'
                },
                tasks: [ 'transport' ]
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Run your task as `grunt multi` and it will iterate over all the directories in `modules`, running the transport config for each one.

Full documentation is available at https://github.com/neekey/grunt-multi. Hope this helps.

Comment: hi Ben, thanks for your help. however, i'm not sure grunt-multi can solve my problem completely. casue i have sub-directory in the file structure, so it's a little complicate

Comment: actually, i write a custom grunt task to solve this problem, the basic idea is to use nodejs fs.readdirSync(),and fs.statSync() function, to go throught the directoies, and then invoke grunt.task.run() for several times. each time i create a new target with the name "buildN"